# How merge gz files from postgres dump into one big file?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

There is a folder with postgres dump files like:

```
0001.dat.gz
0001.dat.gz
...
6000.dat.gz
toc.dat
```

How merge all these files into single gz archive which is recognized by postgres during restoring?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have the directory format.  pg_restore will recognize that format.  I don't think there is any supported way to convert it to one of the other formats.  You can tar it up into a single file, but you will have to untar it before restoring.  Next time you run pg_dump, you should tell it to use the format you want used.

There are subtle differences in the toc.dat file between the directory format and the tar format, so if you just uncompress and then tar up the directory, it will not work (at least in my hands). It does work the other way around, however.